# Can you put an ad at the bottom insted of an banner in top

Tags: android, xml

I wonder if can get my ads on the bottom of screen insted of on  the top i runes the app i have this xml
Ben this is the new now i get errors please help me i dident understand where to put all the buttons and textview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="fill"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="contentDescription" >

        <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:layout_above="@id/ad"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@drawable/cherries" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cherries"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        android:minWidth="200dp" />

     <com.google.ads.AdView
         android:id="@+id/ad"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-9703280417137355/6644841052"
         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" >
     </com.google.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to stick it in a `RelativeLayout` and align it to the bottom of the parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:layout_above="@id/adview"
        >

        .. put content here

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```